# Switching a Large Current with a Tiny Switch

Tags: power-supply, switches

I have a SPDT switch that can switch .3A @ 5V. I would like to use it to switch 1A @ 9V which will then be fed into a 7805 linear regulator.

[This is the design that I have come up with.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Lbpw.png)

[image]

I have run some simulations on this circuit and it appears to work. Is there anything else I should do? Should I toss in a resistor somewhere?

I'm planning on using [this switch](http://www.mouser.com/Search/ProductDetail.aspx?R=SSSS810701virtualkey68800000virtualkey688-SSSS810701). I don't have a particular MOSFET in mind, but it should be cheap and SMD.

Comment: Supply MOSFET datasheet link (this one or P Channel if you change). Your regulator will need some filter caps at input and output - see regulator data sheet.Regulator will dissipate 4 Watts. Heat sink will be needed. If using SMD you will probably need DPAK or similar to get heat out.

Answer (score 7):

Switching ground is a Bad Idea™. Ground is your reference, and if you need one solid, reliable net in your circuit it should be ground. Don't mess with it.

So I would move the FET to the 7805's input. Almost any P-MOSFET with a low \$R_{DS(ON)}\$ will do, like for instance the [Si2323DS](http://www.vishay.com/docs/72024/72024.pdf). Don't forget to add capacitors to input and output of the 7805, like the [datasheet](https://www.national.com/ds/LM/LM340.pdf) suggests.

**edit**
Russell already drew your attention to 4 W power dissipation in the voltage regulator. Especially for SMT this may require special measures. Russell mentions a D-PAK, which has a large tab for a good thermal contact with the PCB. Remember, for these packages thermal resistance for conduction (to the PCB) is much less than for convection (to the air). You could use a heatsink for a D-PAK

[image]

which mounts *over* the package, not onto it. You can also use a regulator in a TO-263-5 package, which has more pins to drain the heat.

[image]

But the best solution remains a **switching regulator**, which will reduce the dissipated heat to less than half a watt.

Comment: In some cases where ground does not have to be so solid, N-MOSFETs are a better choice for reverse input voltage protection, in my opinion.

Comment: @abdullah - What do you mean, "where ground does not have to be so solid"? Didn't I say you shouldn't interrupt ground?

Comment: Ah, come on. Even with an LED circuit?

Comment: @abdullah - No, gotta be strict! Don't let me see you doing it! :-)

Answer (score 3):

**Capacitors:**

Your regulator will need some filter caps at input and output - see regulator data sheet.

**Power dissipation:**

Regulator will dissipate Power = V x I
= Vin - Vout) x Imax
= (9-5) x 0.9
= 3.6 Watts.

For ~= 4 Watts a heat sink will be needed.
 If using SMD you will probably need DPAK or similar to get heat out.

Your question is of course about more than heatsinking - see [this stack exchanage question and answers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18478/my-linear-voltage-regulator-is-overheating-very-fast/18479#18479) for information or regulator heatsinking.

As you say the switch must be SMD this impilies you are using SMD throughout (but maybe not). At 4W with SMD you will want a largish package that is heatsinkable. DPak and friends or SOT89 would work.

---

As Steven says, placing your switch in the "high side" is a good idea.
If you break ground then the whole regulator subsystem floats to Vin on the "output" side of the switch. If you have other circuitry on the "ground" or "input" side of the switch then it will be at Vin relative to the output (not 0V and not 5V !). This can be "inconvenient" [TM]. (eg having Vout rise from 5V to 9V relative to some other item when you turn the power OFF can ruin your day.

---

Please supply MOSFET datasheet link (this one or P Channel if you change).

---

SOT-89

[image]

D-PAK

[image]