# Powering 2 circuits with the same power supply

Tags: voltage-regulator, power-supply

I have a casio keyboard that runs off 6v and i plan to run it through a velleman voice changer kit that runs off 9v and then finally through passive tone circuit. I was wondering, what is the best way of powering the casio and velleman with one power supply. I'll be housing these circuits in the same case so i want it to be no hassle.

Comment: Please add more information about your project. What do you want to make?

Answer (score 2):

Get a 9 V supply and a 6 V linear regulator.  Run the 9 V device directly from the 9 V supply.  The linear regulator drops the 9 V down to 6 V, which you othen use to run the 6 V device from.

Of course you need to know the currents each device requires, which you didn't say.  Something called a "keyboard" probably doesn't need a lot, but you need to find out.  The linear regulator will dissipate the voltage it drops times the current thru it in heat, so you have to deal with that.  Since the regulator takes 9 V in and makes 6 V out, the voltage drop accross it will be 3 V.  If this keyboard thing draws 100 mA, for example, then the regulator will dissipate 300 mW.  A free standing TO-220 regulator would get noticalby warm at that dissipation, but it shouldn't otherwise be a problem.

Comment: further reading on linear regulator heat and power: [My linear voltage regulator is overheating very fast](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18478/my-linear-voltage-regulator-is-overheating-very-fast)