# Reduce heating in linear power supply

Tags: linear, power-supply

I have a linear regulator in a product which works from 20 to 240VAC: a two stage linear regulator. Stage 1 converts to 18V and stage 2 to 5V. Stage 1 starts heating up as the input voltage increases to 240V. The load on 5 V is about 10mA.

How can I reduce the heating at stage 1?

Comment: You should read [My linear voltage regulator is overheating very fast](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18478/my-linear-voltage-regulator-is-overheating-very-fast), which has much good information on this topic.

Answer (score 3):

A circuit would help but assuming you are rectifying the mains 240V AC input and smoothing it, you'll get a DC level of about 340Vdc. You are dropping this to 18V with a linear regulator and ultimately the load is 10mA (albeit via a 5V linear regulator).

The power dissipation in the 1st stage regulator, when connected to 240Vac will be the dc volt-drop (340 - 18) x 10mA = 3.22W.

Heating is to do with the power being dissipated and unless you change to a switching regulator of some sort this heat will always be generated.

Temperature, on the other hand can be reduced by using a bigger heat-sink on stage 1 regulator.