# LM337 negative voltage regulator gets very hot, is this normal?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, negative

I used the LM337 negative regulator to regulate a +12V from a PC power supply.
And connected the GND to input and the +12 to ground of the circuit, and i got it work (i mean it's regulating the voltage) but the problem is it's get very hot even with heat sink connected to it. Is that normal because i didn't keep it on for a long time.
It used to regulate 12 volts to 3.2 volts.

Comment: How much current?

Comment: 700 mA that used to derive a RGB LED.

Comment: LM337 is a linear regulator, so (12V - 3.2V) * 0.7A = 6 watts of power must be dissapated. Did you use heat sink grease for thermal connection between LM337 and its heatsink? (I assume TO-220 package) If heat sink is just bolted to LM337 there is not always enough thermal contact.

Comment: Thank you for answers. So it is normal to get that much of heat ?

Comment: You'll need to do the thermal calculations to be certain, but 6W will generate a fair amount of heat regardless.

Comment: "So it is normal to get that much of heat?" - You bet! 6W for a single chip is pretty much heat. - Look at your LED: You're probably using a decent heat sink on it, and that's for some 2W only.

Comment: Yes, you have right.

Comment: The 3.2V is between 12V and output - ie floating above ground. Is that where you are putting the load? || Power in = Vin x Iin = 12V x 0.7A = 8.4W. As the LED is taking about 1/4 the voltage it dissipates about 1/4 of the power so | the rest is dissipated elsewhere. Here "elsewhere" is the regulator. Adding a series resistor will move dissipation into the resistor. A m.Alin notes [See answers here - mine and others](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18478/my-linear-voltage-regulator-is-overheating-very-fast) which should help.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do the math:

\$(12\text{V} − 3.2\text{V}) ⋅ 700\text{mA} = 6.16 \text{W}\$

That's a *lot* of power, being wasted directly as heat. Consider using a switching regulator instead. Or an actual LED driver (which will be a switching regulator under the hood).