# Why is LM 317 regulator getting hot?

Tags: voltage-regulator, lm317

I have just made up a adjustable regulator circuit using the LM 317T, the input is approx 33 V, and output 16 V, but the LM 317T when cold regulates at 16 V, but once the LM 317T gets very hot the voltage drops to around 13 V, and is not regulating, my load is drawing approx 150 mA, can anyone please advise.

Comment: The LM317 is in the www.badbeetles.com  website  for various reasons .In your application any linear reg would get just as hot .

Comment: [**Summary: YOU NEED A HEATSINK NOW !!!!! :-}**](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18478/my-linear-voltage-regulator-is-overheating-very-fast)

Answer (score 4):

The input is 33V and the output is 16V - the voltage across the LM317 is therefore 17 volts and the output current is 150mA. This means the power dissipated by the LM317 is 17 x 0.15 watts = 2.55 watts. You need a heatsink - read the data sheet and take note of what the temperature rise is per watt and realize that if the temperature rises much above 150 degC the output starts to shut down to protect itself.

---

Heatsink help using the T0-220FP package data from ST's data sheet: -

If you look in the device's data sheet it will tell you how many degrees in temperature the device's "internals" will warm per watt dissipated into the ambient surroundings. For instance the T0-220FP is 60degC/watt. You are dissipating nearly 3 watts so, without a heatsink, it will be internally (the junction) 180 degC warmer than your ambient local temperature but, of course, it "shuts down" well before 205 degC to protect itself. OK so far? This is the current situation without a heatsink.

There is also another figure called thermal resistance (junction-to-case) and this is 5 degC/watt. If you had an "infinite" heatsink, you would find that the junction (inside the chip) would get only 15degC warmer than the outside world and life would be sweet.

But you can't have an infinite heatsink so you find one like this: -

[image]

From Farnell [here](http://uk.farnell.com/abl-heatsinks/ls185/heat-sink-to-220-21-c-w/dp/595779?mckv=nEl2dTjV&CMP=KNC-GUK-FUK-GEN-SHOPPING-SKU_01_ABL_595779&categoryName=&CAGPSPN=pla&gclid=CjwKEAiAgvyxBRDmuviAj67g-XQSJABTLMcHBbAYOHq3rwCsE-C89KcJ94eUSsxF5xna33ngQpGW_RoCNTXw_wcB&gross_price=true&ost=595779&categoryId=&CAWELAID=120173390001363501). You read the spec and it tells you that its thermal resistance is 21 degC/watt.

Next you add the 5 degC/watt to the 21 degC/watt to get the final thermal resistance, (junction to ambient) of 26 degC/watt. With 3W dissipated you have a temperature rise of 78 degC above ambient (say) 25 degC - this means the device will rise to about 103 degC. This heatsink might be OK but if your electronics is mounted in a box that is a little small, the local ambient may rise by 20 degC so you might have to take extra measures to sort out the extra rise.

I've just been reminded that the 60 degC/ watt (junction to ambient) below: -

[image]

... Is a parallel path to the junction/case + heatsink/ambient thermal resistance so this means the 26 degC/Watt figure falls to 18 degC/watt because parallel thermal resistance is calculated exactly the same way as regular parallel resistors in a circuit.

Alternatively drop the input voltage to 16 V using a buck regulator - it's about 90% to 95% power efficient and would therefore only dissipate about 200 mW but that's another question in case you want to follow that sensible route.

Comment: Would efficiency increase if there was a regulator to 22, then to 16 volts?

Comment: @tuskiomi, no the efficiency stays the same. But the thermal load is spread over two parts instead of one so they don't get as hot or could use smaller heat sinks (but of course two of them instead of one).

Comment: what size of heat sink would i require for nearly 3 watts dissipation,are the LM 317 modules with heat sink as sold on ebay be suitable for my application or would i require bigger heat sink ????

Comment: @daverave see the adds to my answer. BTW I know a musician called daverave - is it you?

Comment: NOTE: ja is in parallel to the jc+cs+sa

Comment: @JonRB very true so this reduces things down from 26 degC/W to 18 degC/W.

Comment: im going to use the LM 317T in a small box which also holds the batteries so will be in a confined space,im planning to use    a module from ebay which is compact but not sure if heat sink will be suitable for my application also considering now being mounted in a box.

Comment: i cannot really use a buck regulator cause my application is a metal detector power supply and any noise from the buck regulator would cause instability in the audio,unless frequency of buck and metal detector oscillator are in sync.

Comment: @daverave Rubbish, the most sensitive type of metal detectors in common use in factories for detecting small particles of metal in foodstuffs use switch mode power supplies. Now these devices are really sensitive and can find easily 1mm diameter piece of iron passing through the search head coils. I've designed one and I estimate the voltage that 1mm of iron produces is in the order of about 40 nano volts and perfectly detectable. Use a buck regulator followed by your LM317 if you want to try this - the buck drops the 33V to maybe 19 volts and the 317 does the regulation to 16V.

Comment: no me not a musician,must be a different daverave.

Comment: im into treasure metal detecting and im trying to get good depth on low conductive items like gold,but one of the biggest problems has been noise which reduces detection depth,i thought maybe the buck would cause more supply noise being not in sync with detector oscillator,ive not done much experimenting with buck regulators so mine was only an assumption rather than fact,i may take another look at buck regulators which could be a better solution to my application.

Comment: It'll give you more battery life too.

Comment: i will take a look at buck converters and more battery power is a bonus cause my battery pack is only 800mah and my load current is about 150 ma which as you can see is not much running time.

Comment: If you feel you've got your moneys worth out of this answer you can mark it as "accepted" - it's not going to collect any more votes now because it's closed but you can, when you find something that feels about right leave a comment here and I'll check it out for you.

Comment: No you need to press a button to accept it hehehe - somewhere underneath the upvote/downvote buttons on this answer.

Comment: i cannot find the accept option

Comment: At the top of my answer (not your question) there is an "up" and "down" arrow on the left hand side of the page - there should also be another symbol below these that is the answer accept button.