# Can anybody explain the heat produced in the circuit during operating and non-operating state

Tags: rectifier, bridge-rectifier

[image]I have designed motor monitoring circuit(Agricultural Purpose) with Stepdown transformer, Rectifier, Relay Module, and processor.I planned to run the module to run 24*7 but I afride that heat will affect the circuit.My circuit working is When the relay module triggered the circuit got closed and the processor will handle remaining work.

Here my Question is if the relay is in Off state(load is connected to NO, No load connected in NC) still my transformer and rectifier circuit get connected to the power supply which will produce heat or it will not produce heat?

Comment: I'm not going to try to answer the question, as the reason for that specific circuit design isn't clear. Some parts in the suggested design *might* be wrong, depending on details which have not been given (e.g. you seem to be sending 9V to a "processor i/p" - depending on the exact details of the "processor", that might be a bad plan; etc. etc.). However I'll just point out that the flyback diode across the relay coil is **the wrong way round**.

Comment: Temperature rise is like Ohm's Law except Power is like thermal current and temperature is like voltage generated [W] * Thermal resistance ['C/W]= Temp rise 'C  and for electrical power P=V*I for V = voltage drop (ΔV=Vin-Vout) on regulator or output to load.  Heat sinks are used  to lower thermal resistance.   Motors will likely draw much more power than a relay, which can be reduced with a FET Switch or more efficient power supply. Learn Ohm's Law then apply it.

Comment: Thanks, Sorry it is 5V dc to the processor I wrongly mentioned 9V. The diode-connected across the relay coil is to provide the path to current flow when the relay coil is de-energized. In a picture, the relay is designed for "Turn Off Delay" so the diode is essential for the circuit.

Comment: Sorry, now I understand what you trying to notify me I will correct my diode position.Thank you very much

Comment: You have enough input now to answer your question BUT this answer of mine will probably be useful in this and similar applications. [**My linear voltage regulator is overheating very fast**](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/18479/3288)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformer, diode bridge, and regulator all will produce heat even if everything else is off or disconnected.  Current flows through the transformer primary even if the secondary has no load at all, and the wire resistance converts some of that current into heat.  The regulator has about 5-10 mA of static current from the input pin to the ground pin even if there is nothing attached to the output, so this produces some heat.  Also, that static current comes from the transformer secondary and through the diodes, so there is more heat produced in those elements.

All of this adds up to very little heat.  The surface temperatures of the components will vary depending on where the circuit is mounted and how much the ambient air is moving around it, but it should be way below anything uncomfortable to touch.  Depending on the relay coil and processor current requirements, the regulator probably will need a heatsink to prevent overheating when the system is on.

Answer (score 2):

If would be good if you added a schematic so we know what you are talking about.

Generally though the transformer will create a little heat when under no load due to losses in the transformer, but not so much heat that you will be able to feel much. Similarly, the rectifier has a little leakage current that makes some minimal heat.

If it is still getting hot, then either the transformer is not sized right or there is something else going on.

When the thing is driving the load of course there will be more current passing through the transformer and regulator and heat will be produced due to the losses in the transformer and the voltage drops across the diodes in the rectifier. With a large load, this can produce significant heating.

UPDATE: Thanks for the schematic. Despite the fact the diode is in backwards, this answer remains basically unchanged. The voltage regulator will, like the rectifier, consume minimal power ( ~24mW ) because of the eight or so milliamps it needs to function when the relay is open.

Answer (score 1):

The regulator draws about 5mA with no load. That's less than 100mW in the regulator even allowing for the transformer having bad regulation and supplying closer to 20V than the ideal 15VDC. It will barely feel warm.

With the relay 'on' (assuming you fix that diode direction!) the regulator will see considerably more dissipation. If the relay is a 9V 40mA type (360mW coil) the regulator could see an additional 0.04 * (15V-9V) = 240mW. If the relay coil **plus the processor draw** is less than about 100mA you won't even need a heatsink, assuming a TO-220 package. If it is more, you may also need to rethink the 1000uF filter cap.

The diodes will run cold. The transistor will see some dissipation during the (slow) switch off. Worst case is Ix*2.25 where Ix is the nominal coil current. So with a 100mA coil the peak dissipation could be 225mA, which is not worrisome even for a TO-92 transistor.

Obviously with the flyback diode incorrectly installed as shown, the transistor and regulator will tend to overheat. I presume your "processor" contains an internal regulator so it runs from 9V.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir.I will fix the error in flyback diode installation.