# How much power does LM7805 dissipate?

Tags: power, voltage-regulator, power-dissipation, lm78xx

I'm using an LM7805 in voltage regulator mode.

- V<sub>in</sub> is 15V
- V<sub>out</sub> is 5V (regulated)
- The attached load draws 200mA

[image: LM7805]

How to calculate how much power the LM7805 would dissipate in this setup (and whether or not I need a heat sink)? Couldn't understand it from looking at the [datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/LM7805.pdf).

---

<sup>P.S. I'm asking because it gets quite hot, which I didn't expect. Checked the attached load, it is around 0.2A, so well within the limit of 1.5A.</sup>

Comment: For a linear regulator, Iout is roughly equal to Iin. All voltage dropped across the pass device is dissipated as heat.

Comment: Wait, this has been asked multiple times, see [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18478/my-linear-voltage-regulator-is-overheating-very-fast).

Comment: Also there is more detailed datasheet [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm340.pdf)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at **package thermal data** section in your datasheet page two.

Depending on the package of the regulator you are using, lets say the thermal junction-ambient coefficient \$\theta_{JA}\$ is roughly \$20°C/W\$.

You've got \$ P = V \cdot I = (15\ \text{V} - 5\ \text{V}) \cdot 0.2\ \text{A} = 2\ \text{W} \$ dissipated as heat.

If your ambient temperature is \$25°C\$, then the regulator would heat up more or less into \$65°C\$.

It is quite hot for sure.

Comment: 2W is about the limit for use without a heatsink.

Comment: Yes, I'm very linearizing here for simplification. The ambient will also heat up which eventually also increase the regulator temperature. Also, in the `NOTE 1` below the package thermal table in the datasheet OP linked there are maximum power dissipation formula and careful warning statement which would be useful for OP while learning this topic.

Comment: Different manufacturers have [*very* different](https://www.petervis.com/electronics/Voltage_Regulator_Heatsink/Heatsink_for_TO-220_Voltage_Regulator.html) thermal resistances.
For TI it's `19 °C/W` (--> 63 °C) for STM `50 °C/W` (--> 125 °C), for Fairchild even `65 °C/W` (--> 155 °C). The latter two will probably die without a heat-sink (see absolute maximum ratings).

Comment: As far I remember, I assumed 20 as a best case for quite hot. +1 for clarifying.