# Use a dropping resistor or a zener diode?

Tags: voltage, zener

I have a situation where I need to power an Arduino Uno R3 from a ~16V power supply.

The problem is I have no idea of the implications of voltage dropping. I think I just need a 100 Ohm resistor.

So, in case I am right, my actual question turns into: When is it better to complicate a circuit with a Zener diode?

I will also attach a photo since I understand it is easier to read from it.

[image]

Edit 1: A neighbor suggested a 4V LED that would also indicate it's working.

Comment: Don't use a voltage divider (resistors) or a zener. Use a DC/DC **converter**

Comment: Read [This SE EE question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/18478/3288) and then [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/18479/3288) and you should have a VERY good idea of what to do. The other answers are also useful - the above one is mine :-).

Comment: Reducing the Vin to theUNO to closer to the processor operating voltage will reduce the heat in the onboard regulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to power it, it is not a good idea. What happens, if your Arduino suddenly draws more current? -> The voltage drop across your resistor increases, the voltage on your Arduino supply decreases. Same case with diode.

Use a simple linear regulator or a switching DC/DC converter module.

Comment: ... and we usually use the battery **negative** as the common or GND (and not the positive).

Comment: this is why it's best to ask, thank you