# Linear Voltage regulator becomes very Hot when connected to Nichrome wire heater

Tags: voltage-regulator, heatsink

I'm trying to build a heating element using nichrome wire 24 gauge. I'm using a 12v linear voltage regulator (L7812CV) as a power adopter which is connected to a rectifier bridge providing 19v. When the power adopter is used with other devices it works well (e.g 12v Fans and Arduino) .But as i have tried to connect the Nichrome wire about 40cm length the heat sink connected to the regulator becomes very hot just in about a minute.Can someone  tell me what's going wrong and how to solve it?

Comment: Nothing's going wrong, linear regulators get hot. Don't use a linear regulator for anything high current.

Comment: Calculate the resistance of your wire. Calculate the current it will draw from your regulator. Calculate the power dissipated in the regulator. Edit the calculations into your question. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: What is Vin. What is current? Also see [My linear voltage regulator is overheating very fast](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/18478/3288)

Comment: Ah -  19V.OK Pregulator to Pload = Vreg:Vload = (19-12):12 = 7:12. Your regulator is dissipating about 60% as much as your wire. See my answer to the question above for ways to address this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nichrome wire acts as a resistive load. Check the resistance of yours and I'm sure you'll find that it's pretty small--under 100 ohms, maybe even 1 ohm. At 12 ohms your circuit draws 1A through the linear regulator. You say that you're inputting 17v and outputting 12v in that regulator--this 5V drop means that it's losing 5W per amp in heat. With a small resistance load, that means that the linear regulator is releasing a lot of heat.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using a 12v linear voltage regulator (L7812CV) as a power adopter which is connected to a rectifier bridge providing 19v.

In this circuit the linear regulator is acting as a resistor with a resistance set so that 12v is dropped across your heater and 7v dropped across your regulator.  Since the same current flows through both and the voltages are almost equal, your regulator is dissipating nearly as much heat as your heating element.

A better design would be to run the nichrome wire off of 19v (perhaps by putting a little more of it in series) so that you don't need the regulator or to get a switching regulator so that you don't have to dissipate all that heat.

Comment: If i connect the heater independently. Can i use a MOSFET or a relay so as to sometimes turn off the heater in order to control the Heat in a box maybe?

Comment: @Dr.GeekNerd Yes, of course.