# What is the most efficient way to convert high Vin DC to low Vout DC?

Tags: voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, texas-instruments, dc-to-dc

I need voltage regulator to convert high range of Vin 20-60V to fixed 5 or 12V and the maximum output current is 200mA. What could be the efficient way to do this?

Comment: Google: Step-Down converter

Comment: [This](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18478/my-linear-voltage-regulator-is-overheating-very-fast/18479#18479) SE Q&A should help.