# Overheating Linear Voltage Regulator In Lexicon Omega Audio Interface. Can I Swap With Reduced Amperage To Avoid Heat Probs?

Tags: power-supply, transistors, linear-regulator, digital-audio

I have a Lexicon Omega USB Audio Interface that's overheating.

Already tried several heatsinks, including the biggest one I could get (6"Hx2.5"Wx.5"D) with optimized cross-cut vertical fins, mica isolators, & prolimatech pk-1 cpu grease to help transfer.

Also replaced the LVRs to see if they had degraded with time, using TI parts to see if they would be better quality.

Still overheats & shuts itself off.

The 2 in question are the TI equivalents of an ON 7812CT and an ST L7912CV.

Not sure, but I think it may be the 7912CV because it's 1.5 Amp.

Since the power-input to this thing is 9V at 1.3mA = 11.7W,

And the 7812 is a +12V at 1.0A,

Is it crazy of me to think the 7912CV (-12V, 1.5A) could just be swapped for the 1.0A version of that one?

Something like an ON MC7912CTGOS-ND which is -12V at 1.0A?

-You know, without destroying the unit, causing fires, tsunamis, reflowed Microsoft Word Docs, etc.

Sorry, but I don't know much about electrical engineering at all.

Lexicon seems to have made an absolute lemon here. Converts from AC to DC inside the box with no OEM heatsinks or case-vents of any kind.

Another reason I ask about the LVR swap, is I hesitate to cut/drill the case & would like to avoid it if possible.

Thank You Very Much for any Time, Attention, or Help!

-Will

PS: Error-behavior is that it cuts out after playing a few hours of pink noise & the internal "circuit breaker" trips, along with a power-fluctuation of everything else on that outlet.

PPS: The other transistor on that side of the board is a TIP122 which barely gets warm at-all. It's the 2 LVRs that are constantly on "barbecue mode".

Comment: Maybe something else is broken inside the unit that consumes more current, and the voltage regulators heat anyway no matter how you change them? Perhaps the power supply is faulty, have you checked it? But what is it that you talk about the outlet power fluctuation, maybe you have an issue with your mains outlet, not with audio interface at all? There is no logic trying to fix the audio interface if it is clear that some whole outlet power fluctuates!

Comment: XY problem. Do you think Lexicon made a mistake in their deisgn and have tens of thousands of the same problem cases in the field?

Comment: @Winny: Yes. This unit known for extremely-spotty reliability, across many forums.

Comment: @Justme: Fair statement. Have not tested PSU. Mains reputation is rock-solid. Good points!

Comment: Send it back and require your money back?

Comment: @winny: Sadly impossible now.

Comment: I understand. Strange. I have the very same device and have never had any issues with it. If I would attempt something similar, I would unsolder it and make a daughterboard with wires down to the original pads.

Comment: @winny: Then you're one of the lucky few! Interesting idea on the daughterboard. I think I may use Tim's info, turn my original idea around, and try the 1.5A 7812 because it may be higher-rated and run farther-away from the circuit-breaker temperature since it will still output 12V but have more operating-tolerance. I'll probably still have to drill holes or run case-open, though. I even put mini-sinks on every large chip on the digital board, too!

Comment: @winny: Also! -Don't know if you'll see this, but I somehow just thought of this now. If you have a Lexicon Omega, I would REALLY be interested to know what part numbers your Linear Voltage Regulators are on the "analog board". It's the shorter of the 2, with the 3 LVRs sticking off the edge. As before, the top one is a TIP122 and doesn't overheat, but the lower 2 do get really hot. I wonder if we both got the same parts? If you're too busy or worried about ESD-risks to open the unit, I understand.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it crazy of me to think the 7912CV (-12V, 1.5A) could just be swapped for the 1.0A version of that one?
>
> Something like an ON MC7912CTGOS-ND which is -12V at 1.0A?

You're misunderstanding the current rating of a voltage regulator.  It is physically impossible for a two-terminal source to control both the voltage and current at the same time -- the load pulls a current that's a function of the voltage that it sees (or it develops a voltage across its terminals that's a function of the current you shove into it).

If the load pulls 0.75A at 12V, then it's going to pull that same 0.75A at that voltage whether the regulator is rated at 1.0A or 1.5A or 150A.

The LM7912 is a voltage regulator.  That means, it regulates voltage.  As stated above, **that** means that it holds the same voltage **no matter what the current draw is** -- up to the point where things go sideways.

The voltage rating is what it **does**.  The current rating (1A or 1.5A) is what it can **stand**.  If you put in a lower-rated part in there, it'll probably just overheat quicker.

If it takes a couple of hours of continual use to have a problem, then it's almost certainly a problem with getting heat out of the case.  Normally I'd recommend that you put a fan in there, but it looks like it's a pro audio part -- so I'm going to *suggest* that you find a small, really quiet fan, and put it in there, and my apologies if it's just too noisy for whatever you're doing.

Or, if there's no holes in the case now, you may be able to make it into a happy camper by drilling holes in the top & bottom so that air can flow up the heat sink (and make sure the heat sink fins are vertical).

Comment: Hey Tim, I think ultimately you're probably right on vents. Was just thinking viz this thread (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18478/my-linear-voltage-regulator-is-overheating-very-fast) that I could downgrade that -12V 1.5A to dump some heat by getting rid of 6W. Not sure on very long-term behavior, but tested again last night w/ laser-thermo & 7812 seems to run at 117F within 30-ish mins of pink noise, 7912 more like 109F. Also that OKI 78SR converter too noisy for audio. Argh! Probs. try case-open just to see...

Comment: You're still misunderstanding how voltage sources and loads work.  I've edited my answer, hopefully in a way that clarifies.  Just because your -12V regulator is *rated* at 1.5A, that doesn't mean that your circuit is drawing 1.5A from it, and it certainly doesn't mean that changing the regulator will change the amount of current drawn -- and if it does, it'll affect the voltage.

Comment: Ok, that does make it a little bit clearer now! Back to drilling the box, I guess. Darnit! Thanks again very much!