# L7805CV operating temperature

Tags: voltage-regulator, temperature, overheat

I have an L7805CV powering an Arduino and a serial communication chip from a 12 V supply. Nothing else is powered by the L7805CV as the LED strip is powered via a TIP120 transistor and 12 V.

However, the L7805CV gets up to 33 degrees, is that normal with such a small current draw?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is a small current draw? Have you measured it?

Comment: It could be normal, without knowing the total current draw it's hard to say.  There's 7 V across the device, so 100 mA of current draw would be 0.7 W and a temperature rise of about 65 C/W or 45 C, so completely possible with much less current than 100mA

Comment: 33°C is a good temperature.

Comment: I think L7805 is way hotter than 33°C. Look at where you found hottest point. From picture it seem that it is on plastic molding and not on the metal tab where it would be expected. Problem is that thermal camera can have problems with shiny metals (low emisivity).

Comment: My answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/18479/3288) addresses heatsinking and temperature rise and ... "

Comment: The rise is expected. Trise = (Vin-Vregout)x Iload x Rth_ja_regulator. See my above answer for a lonnnnger version of that.  33C is very acceptable.

Comment: What thermal camera are you using. A nice toy. I have a CAT S61.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TO220 package without heatsink should have about 60°C/W thermal resistance to ambient (RthJA). So if it is 9°C hotter than ambient (delta T), then it's dissipating about deltaT/RthJA = 0.15W which corresponds to 21mA with a voltage drop of 7V (12V to 5V).

That current is in the range of what your board would draw, so everything seems normal here.